# Can not update my apk on device

Tags: android

I can not update my apk on destintion device.
I have signed it, but in log i get

```
    Log Collector version: 1.1.0
 Device model: LG-P690
 Firmware version: 2.3.4
 Kernel version: 2.6.35.10-perf+
lg-electronics@LGERP-BLD-LNX )
#1 PREEMPT Mon Dec 12 17:04:15 MSK 2011
 Build number: GINGERBREAD

Intent PendingIntent{409f4dc8: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 22:59:13.949 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 22:59:13.949 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{40a9b800 Intent PendingIntent{40a405d8: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 22:59:14.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:14.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:20.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:20.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:23.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:23.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:26.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:26.529 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:33.139 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.lge.launcher/.Launcher } from pid 1565
12-02 22:59:34.699 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.infraware.polarisviewer/com.infraware.polarisoffice.OfficeMainActivity bnds=[82,127][158,223] } from pid 1879
12-02 22:59:35.539 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:35.539 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:36.279 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/FluffyBag-46.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity } from pid 7383
12-02 22:59:37.719 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/FluffyBag-46.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) } from pid 7252
12-02 22:59:37.969 W/ActivityManager( 1565): No content provider found for:
12-02 22:59:38.539 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:38.539 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:40.569 W/ActivityManager( 1565): No content provider found for:
12-02 22:59:41.539 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:41.539 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:41.849 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 22:59:41.849 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{40a6dc60 Intent PendingIntent{409acae0: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 22:59:42.329 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 22:59:42.329 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{409979e8 Intent PendingIntent{407f1818: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 22:59:42.959 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 22:59:42.959 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{40873420 Intent PendingIntent{40879110: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 22:59:43.459 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/FluffyBag-46.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity } from pid 7383
12-02 22:59:44.939 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/FluffyBag-46.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) } from pid 7252
12-02 22:59:45.149 W/ActivityManager( 1565): No content provider found for:
12-02 22:59:47.539 W/ActivityManager( 1565): No content provider found for:
12-02 22:59:48.699 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 22:59:48.699 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 22:59:50.009 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/FluffyBag-46.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity } from pid 7383
12-02 22:59:52.139 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/FluffyBag-46.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) } from pid 7252
12-02 22:59:52.349 W/ActivityManager( 1565): No content provider found for:
12-02 22:59:54.209 W/ActivityManager( 1565): No content provider found for:
12-02 22:59:56.699 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.lge.launcher/.Launcher } from pid 1565
12-02 23:00:00.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:00.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 23:00:01.429 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector/.SendLogActivity } from pid 1879
12-02 23:00:03.549 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) } from pid 7306
12-02 23:00:03.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:03.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 23:00:06.159 I/ActivityManager( 1565): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.email/.activity.MessageCompose (has extras) } from pid 7306
12-02 23:00:06.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:06.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 23:00:09.699 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:09.699 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 23:00:10.859 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 23:00:10.859 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{408f6828 Intent PendingIntent{40a97258: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 23:00:11.329 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 23:00:11.339 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{40905188 Intent PendingIntent{408fb3b8: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 23:00:11.979 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 23:00:11.979 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{40972030 Intent PendingIntent{409076c8: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 23:00:12.699 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:12.699 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 23:00:15.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:15.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 23:00:30.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:30.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
12-02 23:00:36.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
12-02 23:00:36.689 D/StatusBarPolicy( 1653): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25503 curHPLMN=25503
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
12-02 23:00:38.089 I/dun_service( 1475): received event(DUN_EVENT_USB_UNPLUG) in state(DUN_STATE_USB_UNPLUG)
12-02 23:00:38.089 I/dun_service( 1475): Ignoring the event DUN_EVENT_USB_UNPLUG in USB_UNPLUG_STATE
12-02 23:00:38.089 I/dun_service( 1475): Moved to state(DUN_STATE_USB_UNPLUG)
12-02 23:00:38.139 E/Tethering( 1565): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 289<!> attempting to remove unknown iface (usb0), ignoring
12-02 23:00:38.139 D/bwx.qb  ( 4540): <!>com.bwx.qs.battery.BatteryService$BatteryStateReceiver 62<!> battery state: level=37, charging=false
12-02 23:00:38.149 D/bwx.qb  ( 4540): <!>com.bwx.qs.battery.BatteryWidget 85<!> widgets updated
12-02 23:00:39.879 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 23:00:39.879 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{4088c480 Intent PendingIntent{408faa70: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 23:00:40.349 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 23:00:40.349 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{40800710 Intent PendingIntent{40834ba0: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 23:00:40.989 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): removeUpdatesPI(intent)
12-02 23:00:40.989 V/LocationManagerService( 1565): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{4069b9c8 Intent PendingIntent{407500c0: PendingIntentRecord{407f8698 com.google.android.apps.maps startService}}}mUpdateRecords: {}
12-02 23:00:42.079 I/dun_service( 1475): Post event 1
12-02 23:00:42.079 I/dun_service( 1475): received event: DUN_EVENT_USB_UNPLUG
12-02 23:00:42.079 I/dun_service( 1475): received event(DUN_EVENT_USB_UNPLUG) in state(DUN_STATE_USB_UNPLUG)
12-02 23:00:42.079 I/dun_service( 1475): Ignoring the event DUN_EVENT_USB_UNPLUG in USB_UNPLUG_STATE
12-02 23:00:42.079 I/dun_service( 1475): Moved to state(DUN_STATE_USB_UNPLUG)
12-02 23:00:42.109 E/Tethering( 1565): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 289<!> attempting to remove unknown iface (usb0), ignoring
12-02 23:00:42.129 D/bwx.qb  ( 4540)
```

Comment: post more of your logcat. (without filter)